# Center image in Tablex on RDLC Reports

Tags: c#, rdlc

Could anybody helped me to center image in table of RDLC, i put an image in Table's row an another row below i centered image description but image is not in center. 
thanx in advance

Answer (score -5):

Put your image into `Rectangle(from ToolBox)`. Move the rectangle (with mouse **or** Arrow + CTRL buttons) to place it in the center of cell.